# How should be configured specialized scheme to perform logic unit test on iOS-based devices

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

In the document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html) Apple says:

> Because Xcode cannot run logic unit tests on iOS-based devices, you
>   should configure specialized schemes to perform them.

My question is:

How should be configured specialized scheme to perform logic unit test on iOS-based devices?

Comment: Why do you want to run tests on device?

Comment: @JonReid I have no preferences over the platform: device vs simulator. In my understanding a scheme is not constrained to a platform, I can chose a simulator, device or generic iOS device for the same build.

Comment: Then what is your question?